# Using Static Application Files as Card List Icon

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Application Express 20.1 to set up a simple hub for routing people to other APEX apps/websites.  I would like to use a card list with some custom icons that my management put forth.  I've:

1. Uploaded the images to the static application files
2. Created the static list and tagged the list items with the image from the static application files in the Image/Class field
3. Set the template options to 'display icons' in the list region attributes

But when I run the page the images don't show where the icon normally would.  I've changed the icons to fa images, just to make sure they work and they do.  Am I missing a step or is there some kind of file requirement for these images to be used as a list card icon?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you have to create a new template for cards lists or modify the existing one.

In the template definition found in Shared Components > Templates, find the item you're looking for (in this case it's Cards) and click on it.  Within that you'll need to change the "List Template Current" and "List Template Noncurrent" sections.  Below is how the template is originally configured:

```
<li class="t-Cards-item is-active #A04#">
  <div class="t-Card">
<a href="#LINK#" class="t-Card-wrap" #A05#>
  <div class="t-Card-icon u-color #A06#"><span class="t-Icon #ICON_CSS_CLASSES#"><span class="t-Card-initials" role="presentation">#A03#</span></span></div>
  <div class="t-Card-titleWrap"><h3 class="t-Card-title">#TEXT#</h3><h4 class="t-Card-subtitle">#A07#</h4></div>
  <div class="t-Card-body">
    <div class="t-Card-desc">#A01#</div>
    <div class="t-Card-info">#A02#</div>
  </div>
  <span class="t-Card-colorFill u-color #A06#"></span>
</a>
```

You will need to change the t-Card-icon section so it references an image source rather than the Icon CSS class.

```
<li class="t-Cards-item is-active #A04#">
  <div class="t-Card">
<a href="#LINK#" class="t-Card-wrap" #A05#>
  *<div class="t-Card-icon u-color #A06#"><img src="#IMAGE#"></img> </div>*
  <div class="t-Card-titleWrap"><h3 class="t-Card-title">#TEXT#</h3><h4 class="t-Card-subtitle">#A07#</h4></div>
  <div class="t-Card-body">
    <div class="t-Card-desc">#A01#</div>
    <div class="t-Card-info">#A02#</div>
  </div>
  <span class="t-Card-colorFill u-color #A06#"></span>
</a>
```

Changing the image source to #IMAGE# will reference whatever you have set up in your list configuration for that list item in the Image/Class field.